# org.hibernate.WrongClassException

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a project about figure skating.
I've got a Person class and three subclasses: Skater, Coach and Choreographer.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    private String idPerson;
    private String name;
    private String sex;
    private Calendar birthday;
    private String info;
... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_skater")
public class Skater extends Person {
    private List<Result> resultsByIdSkater;
    private List<SkaterCoach> skaterCoachesByIdSkater;
    private List<SkaterCountry> skaterCountriesByIdSkater;
    private List<SkaterChoreographer> skaterChoreographersByIdSkater;
...getters and setters
```

Coach and Choreographer are similar.
It's obvious that the real Person can be Coach, Choreographer and Skater at the same time.
I want to do something like this:

```
    CoachDao coachDao=new CoachDaoImpl();
    ChoreographerDao choreographerDao=new ChoreographerDaoImpl();
    Coach coach= (Coach) coachDao.findByName("SERHII VAYPAN").get(0);
    Choreographer choreographer= (Choreographer) choreographerDao.findByName("SERHII VAYPAN").get(0);
```

But I have

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=980ae71847e343f9a15755625456bf40] was not of the specified subclass [ru.fsinfo.entity.Coach] : loaded object was of wrong class class ru.fsinfo.entity.Choreographer
```

I understand that I can do it in different sessions. But for some reason I want to do it within one session. Is it possible?